# jQuery check prop. of Radio and uncheck onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

So here is the code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="../../fuctions/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../fuctions/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../fuctions/functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../fuctions/jq.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topbar">
            <div id="title"><!--Title-->
                After Landing
            </div>  
            <div id="leftnav">
                <a href="../../index_aerosoft.html">Home</a>
                <a href="katana_checklist_all.html">Overview</a><!--AllChecklist-->
            </div>
            <div id="rightnav">
                <a href="katan_checklist_engineshut-downl.html"id="a_next">Next</a></div><!--NextPage-->
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <ul class="pageitem">
                    <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()">
                        <span class="name">Wing Flaps -<font color="red"> UP
                        </font></span>
                        <input name="1" type="radio" value="other" />
                    </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                    <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()">
                        <span class="name">Carburetor Heat -<font color="red"> OFF
                        </font></span>
                        <input name="2" type="radio" value="other" />
                    </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                    <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()">
                        <span class="name">Exterior Lights -<font color="red"> as required
                        </font></span>
                        <input name="3" type="radio" value="other" />
                    </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                    <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()">
                        <span class="name">Electric Fuel Pump -<font color="red"> OFF
                        </font></span>
                        <input name="4" type="radio" value="other" />
                    </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <a class="noeffect" href="#" onClick="resetChecklist();">Reset Checklist</a><!--ResetChecklist-->
                <br /><br />
                <a class="noeffect" href="#" onClick="openxyzDE();">xyz</a>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And i got a function that check for "radio is checked and change colour"

```
function checkChanges()
{

    $('.radiobutton font').attr('color', 'red');

    $('.radiobutton :checked').closest('.radiobutton').find('font').attr('color', 'green');
}

$(function()
  {
  checkChanges();
  $('.radiobutton :radio').on('click', checkChanges);
  });
```

I want to add to that code a function that uncheck the Radio if its checked and been clicked again (onClick) this should also change the colour back to red.

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections...

1. Remove the space before the `:checked`. Change:

   ```
   $('.radiobutton :checked').closest('.radiobutton').find('font').attr('color', 'green');
   ```

   To:

   ```
   $('.radiobutton:checked').closest('.radiobutton').find('font').attr('color', 'green');
   ```
2. You need to use `input[type="radio"]` here. Change:

   ```
   $('.radiobutton :radio').on('click', checkChanges);
   ```

   To:

   ```
   $('input.radiobutton[type="radio"]').on('click', checkChanges);
   ```

Comment: doesnt work for me, maybe i do something wrong does you have the full code for me please?

Comment: Can you do a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that I will edit and send you back... :)